# how to prevent WPF MediaKit MediaClosed fired

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-mediakit

I have a WPF window, there is a `ContentPresenter` inside it, and two User Controls (one host `MediaUriElement`, the other host other things) and two buttons (to switch between User Controls).

When I switch to `MediaUriElement` User Control, I assign a video Uri to it, and the video play very well, then I switch to the other User Control, at this time, the `MediaClosed` event fired, when I switch back, the video cannot be played.

I want the video can be played from the beginning or continue play at last switch away, How shall I do?

Very appreciated for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MediaElementBase` (and descendants) hook on the Unloaded event and close the media. Unclosed media still hold some resources.

You can change this behaviour by the `MediaElementBase.UnloadedBehavior` property. Set it whatever else than `MediaState.Close`. But be careful: you have to call `Close()` by yourself then, otherwise you can have memory leaks in your app.